# How to do css media query equivalent within javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to change the javascript below so that if the screen resolution is 768px wide or lower, the header_height variable is reduced to 50 instead of 100, otherwise it stays at 100. Thanks in advance for all assistance!

```js
<script>
$(window).scroll(function () {
     var elem = $('.header');

     var header_height = 100;
  var header_top   = elem.offset().top;
  var current_top  = $(this).scrollTop();

     if (current_top > header_height && !elem.hasClass('fixed'))
  {
      elem.addClass('fixed');
   $('body').addClass('fixed-padding');
     }
     else if(current_top <= header_height && elem.hasClass('fixed'))
  {
      elem.removeClass('fixed');
   $('body').removeClass('fixed-padding');
  }
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the window width using [`window.innerWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth), and combine this with a ternary operator to set the value of `header_height`:

```
var header_height = (window.innerWidth <= 768) ? 50 : 100;
```

It's worth noting that in order to correctly detect changes in the user's window, you should also hook into the `onresize` event, as suggested in Soviut's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `window.resize` event, not the `scroll` event to run your check. The resize event will fire when a mobile browser changes orientations (portrait to landscape, etc).

```
$('window').on('resize', function() {
  // do size checks here
});
```

It's worth noting that the `resize` event fire very frequently on most browsers so you might want to "debounce" it. Additionally, you should also cache your query selectors *outside* of the resize event handler function. You don't want it re-selecting the same elements over and over again each time a resize event fires.